# "Sensual / likes physical pleasures" without sexual connotation?

Tags: phrase-requests, connotation

Looking for a word or expression to describe someone who's very into physical sensations, liking things varying from climbing, to baths, to working with their hands. "Sensual" is the closest word that I know, but that has a very sexual connotation, which I'd like to avoid. Similarly for "liking physical pleasures

Thanks!

Comment: 'sybaritic' might be one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Eating delicious food and relaxing in a warm bath are [sensuous](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/sensuous) activities.*

*Swimming is our most [sensuous](http://www.thedailybeast.com/articles/2012/04/08/swimming-to-health-excerpt-of-lynn-sherr-s-swim-why-we-love-the-water.html) sport*.

[sensuous](http://grammarist.com/usage/sensual-sensuous/): perceived by or affecting the senses.

Comment: +1 I was just taught about the difference between these two in a poetry class

Answer (score 2):

I think that ***tactile sensation*** may refer to the physical pleasure you are describing:

[Tactile](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tactile):

> - Of or connected with the sense of touch:
>
>   - *vocal and visual signals become less important as tactile signals intensify*

[Tactile/tactual sensation](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tactile+sensation) :

> - ***the sensation produced by pressure receptors in the skin**;
>
>   - "she likes the touch of silk on her skin".

The Free Dictionary

Answer (score 0):

*Hedonist* may cover what you are looking for:

> A person whose life is devoted to the pursuit of pleasure and self-gratification